# Change Detection issue -- Why is this changing when it's the same object reference with On Push

Tags: angular

I thought I was pretty clear on how Angular Change detection works after this discussion: [Why is change detection not happening here when [value] changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293368/why-is-change-detection-not-happening-here-when-value-changed)

But take a look at this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/jb2k7U3TfV7qX2x1fV4X?p=preview

```
@Component({
selector: 'simple',
  template: `
    <div (click)="onClick()">
      {{myData[0].name}}
    </div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Simple {
  public @Input() myData;
  constructor() {
  }
  public onClick() {

  }
}
```

Click on a, it's changed to c

I understand that the click event triggers change detection on the App level, but [myData]="testData" is still referring to the same object, and I am using On Push on Simple, why does a get changed?

Comment: With OnPush, change detection is not supposed to happen when the @Input() is the same object by reference

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's by design.

If you have component with `OnPush` change detection then its `detectChangesInternal` function won't be triggered unless one of four things happens:

### 1) one of its `@Inputs` changes

**~2.4.x**
[image]

**~4.x.x**
[image]

**Note:** `@Input`s should be presented in template. See issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20611 and [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20611#issuecomment-346875634)

### 2) a bound event is triggered from the component (**that is your case**)

Caveats: There is some difference here between 2.x.x and 4

[Angular ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush with child component emitting an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607202/angular-changedetectionstrategy-onpush-with-child-component-emitting-an-event)

**~2.4.x**
[image]

**~4.x.x**
[image]

### 3) you manually mark the component to be checked (`ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()`)

### 4) async pipe calls `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` internally

```
private _updateLatestValue(async: any, value: Object): void {
  if (async === this._obj) {
    this._latestValue = value;
    this._ref.markForCheck();
  }
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L137

---

In other words if you set `OnPush` for component then after the first checking component's status will be changed from `CheckOnce` to `Checked` and after that it's waiting as long as we do not change status. It will happen in one of three things above.

See also:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11678#issuecomment-247894782

There are also good explanations of how angular2 change detection work:

- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html
- https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f

Here is **[Live Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9rzgqOSCpK8Lqzu5JM4i?p=preview)**(Thanks to Paskal) that explains `onPush` change detection. (`Comp16` looks like your component. You can click at this box).

Comment: Look at Live Example

Comment: Thanks.  The Live Example link is broken.  But I actually watched Paskal's talks on youtube before I asked the question.  For some reason I missed the part about events triggering the change detection with OnPush components.  I was under the impression that the reason for OnPush to be FAST is that it will even ignore the events and only detect the @Input().  I now know my understanding was wrong

Comment: I've fixed link

Comment: @yurzui, great answer! maybe add [my article link](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) to the post along with Pascal's? :)

Comment: @yurzui will setTimeout inside child component with onPush strategy trigger a change detection cycle?

Comment: @alt255 Nope. You can call `markForCheck` inside `setTimeout` to run change detection cycle