# DOM not updated in Angular before scrolling

Tags: angular

I have a drag-drop directive included in my component. It works by modifying arrays and in this process, I manually modify the arrays as well.

The thing is, that the DOM is only updated once I scroll out of the actual view on the same page and back again. Then everything is as it should be.

Is there any immediate explanation for this behavior? And is there a way to force the update maybe?

Thanks.

I will try to add some code and see if it makes sense:

```
  dropDnD(e, day, employment: EmploymentDto, employee: EmployeeDto) {
    this.activeSource = e.value;
    this.activeTarget = { day: day, employment: employment, employee: employee };
this.copyWatch();
  }
  dragDnD($event, employee: EmployeeDto, day, index) {
    this.activeSourceDay = (+day - 1);
    this.activeSourceArrayIndex = index;
    this.activeSourceWatch = $event.value;
    this.activeSourceEmployee = employee;
    this.activeSourceWatchDay = this.employees[0].employments[0].watchDays[4].watches;
  }

  copyWatch() {
        this.planningTable.loadingIndicator = true;
        const sourceEmp = this.employees.find(x => x.employeeId === this.activeSourceEmployee.employeeId);
        const sourceIndex = this.employees.indexOf(sourceEmp);
        const sourceEmployment = sourceEmp.employments[0];
        const newDate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date(Number(this.selectedYear.id), Number(this.selectedMonth.id) - 1, this.activeTarget.day, 0, 0, 0, 0)));

    this.planService.copyRealisedWatch(this.activeSource.plannedWatchId, this.activeSource.realisedWatchId, this.activeTarget.employment.employmentId, newDate, Number(this.selectedYear.id + this.selectedMonth.id)).subscribe(res => {
        const refreshedEmp = this.employees.find(x => x.employeeId === res.employeeId);
        this.employees[0].employments[0].watchDays[this.activeSourceDay].watches = [];

        const index = this.employees.indexOf(refreshedEmp);

      res.multiplier = this.getRowHeightMultiplier();
      this.employees[index] = res;
}
```

And the html

```
 <div ngxDroppable
      [copy]="false"
      dropZone="watch-target-container"
      (drop)="dropDnD($event, column.name, row['employments'][0], row)">

  <div *ngFor="let watch of getDayWatches(row['employments'][0], column.name); let i = index;"
        [style.background-color]="getBackGroundColor(watch, false)"
        [style.color]="getWatchMostReadableColor(watch, false)"
        class="watchcode"
        [contextMenu]="watchMenu"
        [contextMenuSubject]="{watch: watch, employee: value}"
        ngxDraggable="watch-target-container" [model]="watch" (drag)="dragDnD($event, row, toNumber(column.name), i)">
    <div *ngIf="watch.ownedByUser && !watch.closed && !watch.approved">
      <div>{{column.name}}
        <span *ngIf="watch.rejected">!</span>
        <i class="fa fa-arrows move" aria-hidden="true" ngxDragHandle></i>
        <p class="code" *ngIf="showWatchDetails.code">{{i}} {{watch != null ? watch.code : ""}}</p>
        <div [style.background-color]="getBackGroundColor(watch, true)" [style.color]="getWatchMostReadableColor(watch, true)">
          <p *ngIf="showWatchDetails.subcode">gg{{watch != null ? watch.subCode : ""}}</p>
          <p *ngIf="showWatchDetails.time">gg{{watch != null ? watch.timeDesc : ""}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button *ngIf="watch.ownedByUser && !watch.closed && !watch.approved" class="close" (click)="removeRealisedWatch(value, watch.plannedWatchId, watch.realisedWatchId)"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!(watch.ownedByUser && !watch.closed && !watch.approved)">
      <div>
        <span *ngIf="watch.rejected">!</span>
        <span style="padding:0;margin:0;height:0;z-index:-300;" ngxDragHandle></span>
        <p *ngIf="showWatchDetails.code">hh{{watch != null ? watch.code : ""}}</p>
        <div [style.background-color]="getBackGroundColor(watch, true)" [style.color]="getWatchMostReadableColor(watch, true)">
          <p *ngIf="showWatchDetails.subcode">hh{{watch != null ? watch.subCode : ""}}d</p>
          <p *ngIf="showWatchDetails.time">hh{{watch != null ? watch.timeDesc : ""}}e</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button *ngIf="watch.ownedByUser && !watch.closed && !watch.approved" class="close" (click)="removeRealisedWatch(value, watch.plannedWatchId, watch.realisedWatchId)"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input style="width: 100%; padding: 2px;"
          [(ngModel)]="row['employments'][0].watchDays[toNumber(column.name) - 1].currentWatchCodeSearch"
          [typeahead]="watchTemplates"
          (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event, row, row['employments'][0], toNumber(column.name))"
          (typeaheadNoResults)="changeTypeaheadNoResults($event,row['employments'][0].watchDays[toNumber(column.name) - 1].currentWatchCodeSearch)"
          [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="20"
          [typeaheadItemTemplate]="customItemTemplate"
          [typeaheadOptionField]="'code'"
          placeholder=""
          container="body"
          class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried now. Basically the copyWatch() will copy the watch in the db and modify the array - which is done correctly. The view however is not...

Comment: Are you using OnPush?

Comment: Are you sure that all your handlers are executed inside angular zone?

Comment: Yes, the datatable storing the view is onpush.

Comment: Read about when view will be updated with OnPush change detection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312075/change-detection-issue-why-is-this-changing-when-its-the-same-object-referen/42312239#42312239

Comment: Yes, thanks. But the datatable is updated. If I output the datatable twice the one that I am doing the changes in is not updated but the other one is...